# How to get page with ajax?

Tags: html, ajax

I wanna get the page which contains some php and some html code, like this:
Page url: ahax.php?some=1&any=2
Page content:

```
<?php
some php code
?>
some html
<?php
some php
?>
```

I always use "echo" in php file for ajax, now it contains more row of html and php code, it is foolish to use "echo".

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: No clue what you actually want to know here. What is the supposed connection between AJAX, and echo?

Comment: Php file for ajax request which contains echo

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
    $url = 'http://www.google.com';
    echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Not sure that I understood what you want to know... however I hope this is what you are looking for. Please, clarify your question.

Also, have a look at this [very helpful link.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

Comment: I want to get page with ajax. Page has php and html code.